# Return signed document or link to signed document in docusignapi after signing process completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi, electronic-signature

I'm able to login and Get the Embedded Signing View which will return a URL where given user can review the document and sign on it. now we've got the url, user signed it and we redirected it to our application's home page. but how can user see the signed document.

I wanted to send Email to both user and owner after signing process completion with access credentials or URL to see whether document has been signed or not.(I know owner will receive an email with link and subject which says that user has viewed the document)

but how can a user(who just signed the document) see the signed document
(may be this is a silly or dumb question but I'm really not able to find-out any way)

I'm using embeded signing(REST v2).

Answer (score 2):

Generally in your pattern/use case you would have email notifications turned off for embedded signers and use. But there are a couple ways to get the signer back to the signed document:

- You can turn notifications on completion back on if you wish to send a completion email to the signer. You can review this guide to assist you in the right setting https://www.docusign.com/support/how-to-guides/sending-and-signing-options
- Create a DocuSign connect listener and have DocuSign connect send your listener the
  completed document and your site send an email to the signer with a
  link to your site to retrieve your stored copy
- Create a view button that requests another recipient view for the signer so they can
  access the document again just like you did for them to sign